# acronym replacement with it's value using python

Tags: python, twitter, sentiment-analysis

i have dictionary like that i need to replace acronyms in text with it's value in dictionary i use this code but it doesn't give me the appropriate result when i test the function using `acronyms("we are gr8 and awsm")` it should give me we are great and awesome

```
def acronyms(text):
    my_dict = {}
    with open('acronym.txt') as fileobj:
        for line in fileobj:
            key, value = line.split('\t')
            my_dict[key] = value
    acronym_words = []
    words = word_tokenize(text)
    for word in words:
        for candidate_replacement in my_dict:
            if candidate_replacement in word:
                word = word.replace(candidate_replacement, my_dict[candidate_replacement])
                acronym_words.append(word)
    acronym_sentence = " ".join(acronym_words)
    return acronym_sentence
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split` to break your sentence into individual words, then a simple list comprehension to replace desired values:

```
dct = {'gr8': 'great', 'awsm': 'awesome'}
s = "we are gr8 and awsm"

def acronym(s, dct):
  return ' '.join([dct.get(i, i) for i in s.split()])

print(acronym(s, dct))
```

Output:

```
we are great and awesome
```

Comment: Or something like: `re.sub(r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(dct)), lambda m: dct[m.group(0)], s)`