# How to add exception for bad word in regular expression for profanity?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I use Python regular expression to do the profanity check. I have a blocked list of words, but there are some corner cases where I want to add exceptions for the bad words.

For example, I have ['foo', 'bar'] in the blocked list. But I want to exempt cases when it is:

1. "BAR"
2. "foo good"

This is my current approach in Python:

```py
profanity_list = ['foo', 'bar']
pattern_profanity = re.compile(r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(profanity_list)),
 flags=re.IGNORECASE)  # same as r'\b(foo|bar)\b'
s = 'foo BAR foo good Bar'
censor_char = '*'
pattern_profanity.sub(repl=lambda m: censor_char*len(m.group(0)), string=s)
```

This gave me "*** *** *** good ***", but I want the result to be "*** BAR foo good ***". What I should do to include the exceptional cases? Is this feasible in regular expression? Thanks.

BTW, the solution I found is from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259559/acronym-replacement-with-its-value-using-python).

Comment: Welcome to SO! This seems more like a natural language processing task than a regex task. There are so many corner cases and ways of c!rcumv3nt!ng teh l4nguag3 d3t3ktorz. How accurate are you hoping this will be?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```py
import re
profanity_list = ['foo', 'bar']
whitelist = ["BAR", "foo good"]
pattern_profanity = re.compile(
  r'\b(?!(?:{})\b)(?i:{})\b'.format('|'.join(whitelist),'|'.join(profanity_list)))  
s = 'foo BAR foo good Bar'
censor_char = '*'
print( re.sub(pattern_profanity, lambda m: censor_char*len(m.group(0)), s) )
# => *** BAR foo good ***
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Z6wGTP)

The pattern is `\b(?!(?:BAR|foo good)\b)(?i:foo|bar)\b`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fPFqoM/1). It matches:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!(?:BAR|foo good)\b)` - not immediately followed with `BAR`, `foo good`
- `(?i:foo|bar)` - a case insensitive modifier group: `foo` or `bar` matched as...
- `\b` - whole word.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I found that when I changed the pattern to
"\b(?!(?:BAR|good foo)\b)(?i:foo|bar)\b" 
and applied it to the text:
"foo BAR good foo Bar"
It will be "*** BAR good *** ***". Shouldn't "good foo" be protected? Did I miss anything for the use of (?!(?:BAR|good foo)\b)? Thank you. see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y70nfW/1)

Comment: @CX_Lin `good foo` is not a single word. `good foo` in the lookahead does not fail `foo` word, it is matched correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to catch 'foo' but skip it if it is in "good foo", "awesome foo", "foo good", "foo awesome" using regular expression? Basically I want to have a whitelist of some phrases for foo.

Comment: @CX_Lin Yes, see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/Od2hK4).